# read_excel pandas : Value must be ISO datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

El método `read_excel` de pandas me arroja el error `"Value must be ISO datetime format" ValueError: Invalid datetime value 2021- 1-27T13:41:20Z`

El problema es que el error no proviene de una celda del excel sino es cuando pandas carga las propiedades del archivo. Este string es la fecha de modificación del file.
Probé ponerle *parseadores* de fecha como argumento, probé pasarle `dtype=str` pero al ser una propiedad del file esto no lo afecta.

```py
df=pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 265, in __set__
    value = from_ISO8601(value)
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 81, in from_ISO8601
    raise ValueError("Invalid datetime value {}".format(formatted_string))
ValueError: Invalid datetime value 2021- 1-27T13:41:20Z

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 533, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 279, in read
    self.read_properties()
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 173, in read_properties
    self.wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\core.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.modified = modified
  File "***\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 267, in __set__
    raise ValueError("Value must be ISO datetime format")
ValueError: Value must be ISO datetime format
```

Gracias

Comment: cual es el formato de la fecha?

Comment: 2021- 1-27T13:41:20Z, sirve de algo aclarar que el encoding del archivo es utf-8?

Comment: no mucho, solo quiero saber en que formato se encuentra la fecha, así podré ver si el módulo datetime la tiene y especificarlo con ese tipo para que pandas la interprete correctamente.

Comment: a formato no te referis a esto? 2021- 1-27T13:41:20Z

Comment: un formatos común es big endian con representación `aaaa-mm-dd` pero el tuyo tiene una *sintaxis invalida*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una situación que ya ha sido [documentada](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1659), hay alguna aplicación que genera el archivo Excel con propiedades tipo fecha (metadata) en un formato inadecuado, si bien la metadata es algo que para `pandas` no es importante aparentemente si lo es para `openpyxl` que es el que se encarga de leer e interpretar el archivo. En tu caso, se observa que `2021- 1-27T13:41:20Z` no parece una cadena de fecha en formato ISO (ver espacio en el mes).

Posibles soluciones:

1. Abrir el archivo con Excel y salvarlo con un nuevo nombre, esto actualiza las propiedades, fundamentalmente la fecha de creación, y obviamente en el caso de Excel, este genera las fechas con el formato adecuado.
2. Sobreescribir la función `read_properties()` usando la librería [`mock`](https://pypi.org/project/mock/). Por ejemplo podemos hacer que esta función no haga otra cosa que retornar `None`, en este caso que lo importante son los datos en sí, las propiedades del archivo seguramente no nos interesen. La idea es de [Chadfulton](https://foss.heptapod.net/ChadFulton) y esta plasmada en el enlace de más arriba.

   ```
    import mock
    from openpyxl.reader import excel

    with mock.patch.object(excel.ExcelReader, 'read_properties', lambda self: None):
        df=pd.read_excel(filepath)
   ```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Tomé la segunda alternativa ya que es un proceso automático asique la idea es no tocar el archivo. Muchas gracias.